# Syntax Error in Ansible regardless of input when using EC2 module

Tags: amazon-ec2, boto, ansible

When loading any ansible playbook involving the EC2 module, I seem to get the following error:

```
fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "module_stderr": "  File \"/tmp/ansible_j7uw9w39/ansible_module_ec2.py\", line 919\n    except boto.exception.NoAuthHandlerFound, e:\n                                            ^\nSyntaxError: invalid syntax\n", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", "parsed": false}
```

I have tested this with the basic playbook located at https://stackoverflow.com/a/29914701/6150056 as a test case to ensure I wasn't going mad.

Is there something I am missing? I have tried with Ansible 2.1 and 2.2(git) with no change. I feel that it must be a PEBKAC error, as google turns nothing on the issue.

I have verified that boto auth does work, and can find my credentials:

```
Python 2.7.11 (default, Mar 31 2016, 06:18:34) 
[GCC 5.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import boto.ec2
>>> conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region("us-west-2")
>>> type(conn)
<class 'boto.ec2.connection.EC2Connection'>
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was PEBKAC, I was unaware that even locally execing ansible modules (such as EC2) ran a new python instance.

Resolved by setting:

```
ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python2
```

On localhost in /etc/ansible/hosts